# Как в PyCharm убрать из проекта файлы определенного типа, например *.zip?

Tags: python, файлы, pycharm, zip

Как настроить `PyCharm`, что бы он не отображал например архивы и исполняемые `*.exe` файлы в `Python` проекте?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23539618/5741205

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Settings -> Editor -> File Types:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляете `*.exe; *.zip;` и в проекте они больше не отображаются